# Container with several boxes and centered items

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with my code. I need 8 boxes (2 columns with 4 rows) and the content shall be centered (horizontally and vertically). The content will be either an image or a text. The boxes shall have 50% of the width and there shall be space between the two boxes on one line. I tried different ways, but I wasn't  successful.

My current code looks like this:

```css
.desc {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;

}
.text {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc">

  <div class="desc image">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p> 
  </div>
  
  
   <div class="desc image">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="desc image">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p> 
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="desc image">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use Bootstrap for it?

Comment: I'm new to this and don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.desc,
.desc_inner {
  width: 99%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.desc_inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- today -->
<div class="desc">

  <div class="desc_inner">
    <div class="desc image">
      <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <b>Text</b>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="desc_inner">
    <div class="desc image">
      <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <b>Text</b>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="desc_inner">
    <div class="desc image">
      <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <b>Text</b>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="desc_inner">
    <div class="desc image">
      <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <b>Text</b>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An answer with just code and no explanation is not really helpful ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you check the below example, there are 8 boxes which are aligned in 2 columns and 4 rows with contents are vertically and horizontally centred. Check it and let me know if this is what you are looking for

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-flex;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.bg-image {
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/k-POG1-Cp1k/maxresdefault.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3sdass asd assadas asd asdasadas asd asdasdassdaasasd sd as as</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div class='bg-image'>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</section>
```

EDIT

Have updated the snippet with an item with a background-image, the image will automatically resize.

Comment: Yes thats looking good! But the text in "3" is not centered vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Oops, missed a `text-align: center;`. Check now

Comment: Wo great. Thanks a lot! Can you please tell me how I can change the size of the box to a certain size e.g. height: 200px, and make the photo
either resize to fit into the box 
or
cut out the size from the image (I guess by using object-position: center)

Comment: You can set as background-image and give background-size: cover, so that will automatically adjust accordingly

Comment: I have updated the answer snippet with an item having background-image.

Comment: Only one more thing: I want to have a title and a text in the text section. What I have to add to have the title on the top and the text underneath? Right now it is next to each other if I make the title bold.

Comment: You can just add it as div or h4 or any element

Answer (score 2):

Flex Implementation. An another way.

If you want the texts in the tesxt section to be in two seperate lines, use `flex-direction: column;` for `.text` class

```css
.desc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image, .text {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc">

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <b>Text</b>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @rod-san You are welcome. Please approve theanswer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Same here: Only one more thing: I want to have a title and a text in the text section. What I have to add to have the title on the top and the text underneath? Right now it is next to each other if I make the title bold.

Comment: @rod-san If you want the texts in the tesxt section to be in two seperate lines, use `flex-direction: column;` for `.text` class

Comment: @rod-san I have updated the answer with that.

Comment: Ok thanks. Now I have just recognized that for smartphone view it is not very nice. The current format is as follows: 

Image | Text
Text    | Image
Image | Text
Text    | Image

For mobile view it should be:

Image
Text
Image
Text
Image
Text
Image
Text

The format for the second and fourth row have to be changed for the mobile view, in order to have the order image - text - image - text etc.

For mobile view I have this section:

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

Also, does it make sense to have a separate class for each row? 

Can you please help?